# How to define an enum with zero or more Consumers operating on implementations of a common interface?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have something like the below code (simplified as much as possible), which compiles:

```
class Test {

  enum TestEnum {
    ELEMENT1(Test::methodUsingTestclass1);

    <T extends TestInterface> TestEnum(Consumer<T>... consumers) {
    }
  }

  static void methodUsingTestclass1(TestClass1 testClass1) {
  }

  static void methodUsingTestclass2(TestClass2 testClass2) {
  }

  interface TestInterface {
  }

  class TestClass1 implements TestInterface {
  }

  class TestClass2 implements TestInterface {
  }

}
```

Now I want to be able to specify a vararg of `Consumer`s in my `enum`:

```
enum TestEnum {
  ELEMENT1(Test::methodUsingTestclass1, Test::methodUsingTestclass2);

  <T extends TestInterface> TestEnum(Consumer<T>... consumers) {
  }
}
```

This no longer compiles:

> Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: Test.TestClass1 and Test.TestClass2

`T` implements `TestInterface`, and I would like to define one or more `Consumer`s operating on `T`. In other words, a list of method references to methods accepting an implementation class of `TestInterface`.

I have tried this:

```
enum TestEnum {
  ELEMENT1(Test::methodUsingTestclass1, Test::methodUsingTestclass2);

  <T extends TestInterface> TestEnum(Consumer<? extends T>... consumers) {
  }
}
```

But I still get the same compile error.

How can the code be modified so that its constructor accepts zero or more `Consumer`s operating on different implementations of `TestInterface`?

Comment: The problem is, `methodUsingTestclass1` **is not** a kind of `Consumer<TestInterface>`. Namely, it can't consume a `TestClass2`, which a  `Consumer<TestInterface>` should be able to do.

Comment: @Sweeper So, what I want is something like `Consumer<T extends TestInterface>`, which would be able to consume both `TestClass1` and `TestClass2`. But I can't get my head around how to express this in code.

Comment: Even if you could do that, wherever the parameter `consumers` would be used, there would not be enough context for you to send the correct parameter accepted by that consumer. The first test for you is: show us how you use these `Consumer<T>... consumers` from within the enum, you'll see the problem.

Comment: `Consumer<TestInterface>` is such a type of consumer. But note that `Test::methodUsingTestclass1` is not an instance of this type, because the method can only consume `TestClass1`, not "both `TestClass1` and `TestClass2`" How do you intend on using this array of consumers?

Comment: I suspect this is a case of context lost in the introduction of the MVCE. If you're really using these consumers in the enum, then you're probably using a different interface than `Consumer`. Because for the difference between `methodUsingTestclass1` and `methodUsingTestclass2` to be meaningful at invocation time, the functional interface type must be sensitive to concrete `TestInterface` argument. Consumer just doesn't have this notion.

Comment: @ernest_k It is. In fact I am using an own `FunctionalInterface` accepting three parameters and returning a `String`. Which makes it hard for me to show how I itend to use it without fully modifying the question... I tried to keep it simple. But I see what you are saying, and perhaps I just need to rethink my implementation a bit.

Comment: If you accept `Consumer<? extends TestInterface>...` and pass in `ELEMENT1((Consumer<? extends TestInterface>)(Consumer<TestClass1>)Test::methodUsingTestclass1, (Consumer<? extends TestInterface>)(Consumer<TestClass2>)Test::methodUsingTestclass2);` It works. But you can't do anything with the consumers because you don't know what each consumer can accept anymore. You only know that they all accept _some implementation_ of `TestInterface`, which is not enough information for you to be able to pass something into it.